# Colab - automatic authentication of connection to google drive, persistent per-notebook

Tags: python, authentication, google-colaboratory

I'm looking for a way to automate the authentication process when connecting a colab-session to my google drive.

I'd prefer to use the built-in tools for this one, instead of PyDrive.

In short: have the following cell run without having to manually authenticate by logging in and copying the password from the dialogue

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

Comment: Can't you use a browser extension? like:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colab-auto-reconnect/nbcihfbfamjlfiopdcemmohoojdecjid?hl=en

Comment: I've coded this previously but no longer have access to the code. In short, you use Beautiful Soup to capture the auth code that Google provides. This saves you from having to manually copy and paste it and allows automatic authentication. https://towardsdatascience.com/in-10-minutes-web-scraping-with-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-data-professionals-8de169d36319

Answer (score 57):

Automatically mounting to your Drive files is now supported for Colab notebooks which aren't shared by multiple people.

To enable this for a notebook, create a new Drive notebook, open the file browser, and click the 'Mount Drive' button.

[image]

You'll see a permissions dialog like so:

[image]

After you complete the permissions once, you'll see your Drive mounted in the file browser.

[image]

Better still, if you reload the notebook later and reconnect, your Drive will mount automatically with no more `drive.mount` copy/paste required. Your Drive files will just be there.

Comment: Is this a colab pro specific feature ? Because I can not find this Mount Drive button from file menu.

Comment: This method appears to be working. I can still load files from Drive and closing and re-opening the notebook.

Comment: @Thava i have colab pro and i also didn't have this activated in my older notebooks (just the activation code cell is added when i click on the button). Now i tried with a new notebook and it works as Bob says :)

Comment: one gotcha: if you import a notebook, Colab won't let you use the built-in mounting feature. My workaround is to create a blank notebook, mount Drive, import a notebook in a new window, then copy and paste the cells to the original one.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-A/Ctrl-V works for copy-and-paste all cells at one go. It took me a while to figure it out. I hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Working with free colab, Nov 2020

Comment: @mikey in Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+A opens tab search now(

Comment: To copy all cells, you can click in the header of your first cell, hold shift, and down arrow key your way to all cells, and then ctrl+c copy.

Comment: Is there a way to undo this? I.e. if i want to auth against a different google drive under another account I have access to.

Comment: Note working. When you click on the "Google Drive icon", it just create two lines of code in the notebook "from google.colab import drive drive.mount('/content/drive')". Every time the runtime is disconnected, we need to mount the drive again and give authentication –

Comment: What if I'm working with a colab notebook that is shared with many people? Is there any way around this?