# Persistent authorisation for mounting Google Drive in Google Colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab and need to restart my notebook at least once a day due to  their usage limits.

To mount my Google Drive I have the following code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('drive')
```

I then get a prompt:

> Go to this URL in a browser: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxxxxxxx....
>
> Enter your authorization code: ___________________________________________________

---

How can I authorise only once and have that authorisation remembered?

Ideally, that authorisation will have already happened as I'm signed in to Gmail and I can just specify the account email address of the Drive to mount.

However any solution of persistent authorisation where I don't store the auth code in the notebook would be great.

Comment: Did you find any solution to that problem ?

Comment: You're using a normal shared folder which authorization is always required. In order to avoid authorization every time you mount drives, you have to use a shared drive for the team or organization.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't set it to only authenticate once and stay that way for a new runtime, because Colab runs on a VM that is recycled periodically. You can make sure `force_remount` is set to `False` so it doesn't unnecessarily ask you to reauthorize:

```
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=False)
```

But any time you reset the runtime, you will need to reauthenticate with a different authorization code.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way to store the app key & auth token in code so it can be restored?  My other google drive APIs don't need to be constantly reactivated...

Comment: As far as I can see this option has now been enabled. When a drive is mounted it will remain mounted. I don't know if there is a time limit on this though.

Comment: @JaredS Only for that session. If the session has expired, you'll have to re-authenticate

Comment: Doesn't this solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808143/colab-automatic-authentication-of-connection-to-google-drive-persistent-per-n

Comment: Doesn't this solve the problem.