# mounting google drive with google colab without asking authorization code each time

Tags: google-colaboratory

my question is similar to [this queation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752102/persistent-authorisation-for-mounting-google-drive-in-google-colab) but the answer of that doesn't work for me.On that answer he said just click on the "Mount Drive" button. But when I clicked the new cell appears in my code like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pS8T.png). and when I run this cell, It wants me authorization code again!. What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a new notebook, and copy and paste all of the cells from the source notebook there.

The automatic Drive mounting feature requires notebooks that are not shared or modified by others. So, my guess is that the original notebook you are trying to use is shared or is a copy of a notebook authored by others.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it's True. thansk a lot. it saves me a lot of times!!